# Extracting key phrases from documents indexed in solr

Tags: solr, lucene, search-engine

I want to extract the key phrases from the documents indexed in solr and show those phrases as tags for the user.This should be performed after the query has been executed.

For eg: if i type a query `India` and I get the first 50 results on the page, I want to display the **important phrases** from these 50 documents to the user as tags (to do further filtering).

How do I extract key phrases from the text?

Answer (score 1):

I believe [org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.Highlighter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/contrib-highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/Highlighter.html) is what you are looking for.

An example showing it's use can be seen here: http://www.tinhtruong.me/2012/04/highlighting-text-with-lucene.html (among other places).